# How can I solve end of file error in my bash script?

Tags: bash, syntax

I am having some trouble executing the following bash script on Ubuntu 20.04.
The error is "unexpected end of file"
Things I've tried:
*Converted the line endings to unix format.
*Added a "done" statement at the end of the file and also after the "ifs" function.
Note this script was given to me, so I did not write it.
Any help would be apreciated.
Here is the entire script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# add alter.sh to daily cron job

# set your own paths
# update scisola db from sc3 db
python '/home/seismo/scisola/scisola_tools/updatedb_daily/update_db.py'

# set your own credentials
user='user'
password='password'
# set the stations file
# which can be generated through mysql code
stationfile='/home/sysop/scisola/scisola_tools/updatedb_daily/stations.txt'

while read line; do

  IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
  network=${array[0]}
  code=${array[1]}
  priority=${array[4]}

echo "Updating $network.$code priority --> $priority"
# alter priority
mysql -u $user -p$password scisola -e "UPDATE Station SET priority='$priority' WHERE network='$network' and code='$code'";
```

Thanks.

Comment: It definitely needs a `done` somewhere (probably the end?), but I suspect there's also something to redirect input to the loop. I think the script was garbled on its way to you. Check with whoever gave it to you, and find out what's missing.

Answer (score 1):

a `while` loop in bash needs to be end with a `done` statement,

```
while [ <some test> ]
do
<commands>
done
```

a useful webpage which helps to understand loops in Bash is,
https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-loops.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks you forgot the `done` a the end of the `while`, which makes bash think that the file should not end yet.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# add alter.sh to daily cron job

# set your own paths
# update scisola db from sc3 db
python '/home/seismo/scisola/scisola_tools/updatedb_daily/update_db.py'

# set your own credentials
user='user'
password='password'
# set the stations file
# which can be generated through mysql code
stationfile='/home/sysop/scisola/scisola_tools/updatedb_daily/stations.txt'

while read line
do

  IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
  network=${array[0]}
  code=${array[1]}
  priority=${array[4]}

  echo "Updating $network.$code priority --> $priority"
  # alter priority
  mysql -u $user -p$password scisola -e "UPDATE Station SET 
  priority='$priority' WHERE network='$network' and code='$code'";

done
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure the `mysql` line is supposed to be inside the loop (although that conflicts with the indentation), and that there should be an input redirection to make the loop read from a file (maybe `$stationfile`?). But these are really just guesses, it'd be much safer to find out what it's actually supposed to be.